# Move Array value to another specific array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Hi i have this code below that consists of 2 list `Total fruits and random fruits` for my current codes i'm able to click on the values of `Random fruits` and send that array value to the `green fruits array` and vice versa. What im trying to accomplish is to use my `fruits array key value [type]` to map where the value in `random fruit` array should go. is there any easy way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var red = {};
var green = {};
var random = {};
var fruits = [];

var fruits1 = {["fruit"]:"Apple", ["type"]:"1"}
var fruits2 = {["fruit"]:"Tomato", ["type"]:"1"}
var fruits3 = {["fruit"]:"Lime", ["type"]:"2"}
var fruits4 = {["fruit"]:"Guava", ["type"]:"2"}

fruits.push(fruits1,fruits2,fruits3,fruits4);

var randomFruits = fruits.filter(x => x.fruit).map(x => x.fruit);

var key = "Red Fruits";
red[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry','Pomegranate','Rassberry'];

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
green[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado','Lime','Honeydew'];

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
random[key3] = randomFruits;

 function redraw() {
     var combineString = '';
     $.each(red[key], function(index) {
         combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + red[key][index] + '</div>');
     });
     $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

     $.each(green[key2], function(index) {
         combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv greenpill class">' + green[key2][index] + '</div>');
     });
     $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

     var randomString = '';
     $.each(random[key3], function(index) {
         randomString += ('<div class="pilldiv randompill class">' + random[key3][index] + '</div>');
     });
     $('.randomclass').html(randomString);
 }
 
 function listener() {
  
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#randomid div", function() {
            data = this.innerHTML;
   k1 = Object.keys(random).find(k => random[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
            index = random[k1].indexOf(data);
            random[k1].splice(index, 1);
            green[key2].push(data);
            $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + green[key2].length);
            var element = $(this).detach();
            $('#combineid').prepend('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
          });
      });
   
    $('body').on('click', 'div.new-green-fruit', function() {
        data2 = this.innerHTML;
  k2 = Object.keys(green).find(k => green[k].indexOf(data2) >= 0)
        index2 = green[k2].indexOf(data2);
        green[k2].splice(index2, 1);
        random[key3].push(data2);
        $(this).detach();
        var element2 = $(this).detach();
        $('#randomid').prepend('<div class="pilldiv randompill class" >' + element2.html() + '</div>');
    });
 }
 redraw();
 listener();
```

```css
.pilldiv {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: Black;
  margin: 2px;
}
.randompill:after{
    content: "\002B";
    float: left;
 width:16px;
}
.new-green-fruit:after{
    content: "\292B";
    float: left;
 width:16px;
}
.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor:default;
}
.greenpill {
  background-color: SpringGreen;
    cursor:default;

}
.randompill {
  background-color: LightBlue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
 .class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.top {
 margin-bottom: 20px
}
h3{
font-weight: normal;
}
.panel {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
 background-color:white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.new-green-fruit{
background-color: LightBlue;
cursor:pointer;
}
.top{
margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="panel">
        <div style="float:left;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
            <h3 class="class center">Total Fruits</h3>
            <div id="combineid" class="combineclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
        </div>

        <div style="float:right;width:calc(50% - 5px)">
            <h3 class="class center">Random Fruits</h3>
            <div id="randomid" class="randomclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i'm not explaining well enough please do ask

Comment: not getting which values should go where?

Comment: @Onk_r I want to make it so that when i click on `Apple` that value will go to the `Red Fruits Array` based on the mapping of `Fruits Array ["type"]:"1"` so if its 1 it will go to `Red Fruits Array` if ["type"]:"2"` it will go to `Green Fruits Array`

Comment: do you want to change color of that `Apple` ?

Comment: @Onk_r nope no need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply some check like

```
if type == 1 
    prepend
else if type == 2
    append
```

Just update your function as below

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#randomid div", function() {
        data = this.innerHTML;
        k1 = Object.keys(random).find(k => random[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
        index = random[k1].indexOf(data);
        random[k1].splice(index, 1);
        let fromrandom = fruits.find(k => k.fruit == data);
        if(fromrandom.type == 1) {
            green[key2].push(data);
            $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + green[key2].length);
            var element = $(this).detach();
            $('#combineid').prepend('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
        }
        else if(fromrandom.type == 2) {
            red[key].push(data);
            $(".total_count_Red_Fruits").html(key + ': ' + red[key].length);
            var element = $(this).detach();
            $('#combineid').append('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(red)+" "+ JSON.stringify(green)+" "+JSON.stringify(fromrandom));

    });
});
```